# How to modify debug (run) configuration that gets called after saving source file?

Tags: d, ddt

Whenever I save the `app.d` file in DDT, the file gets compiled using `dub build`. What to do, when I want to customize the options, for instance to get unittests (i.e. run `dub build -b unittest`)?

Editing run/debug configurations doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A D project already has different build targets, including one for building (and running) the tests. You can also configure each target with additional DUB options. See more info here: https://github.com/DDT-IDE/DDT/blob/latest/documentation/UserGuide.md#project-building